# Getting Resource not found error While posting batches to the Mailchimp using node Js

Tags: nodes, mailchimp

I am creating the news letter app using node js and Mailchimp. I have created an account on Mailchimp and I have also downloaded the all libraries that I have used in the code. Now after providing all important properties such as API Keys, Unique list Id and Server Name in the request. Still its throwing an error.

I have attached my JS file and error message below. Please help me to resolve this error

```js
const express = require('express');
const body_parser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const app = express();
var path = require('path');
const client = require("mailchimp-marketing");
const axios = require('axios');
const { json } = require('body-parser');
app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/Public')));





app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + 'Public/index.html');
});

app.post('/',function(req,res){

    var firstName = req.body.firstName;
    var LastName = req.body.lastName;
    var Email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    console.log(firstName,LastName,Email,password);



    var data = {
      members:[{
        'email_address' : Email,
        'status'   : 'pending' ,    // "subscribed","unsubscribed","cleaned","pending"
        'merge_fields' :{
            'FNAME' : firstName,   
            'LNAME' :LastName}    }]
        
};
var data1 = JSON.stringify(data);console.log(data1);

const options = {
  url : 'https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/ac7ad45fa0',
  method : 'POST',
   headers: {
      Authorization: "Basic 5223d62ba5e1c655d69dd6de102ebde4-us10"
   },
   body: data1
}

request (options, (error, response, body) => {
  if(error) {
     res.json({error});
     console.log(response.statusCode); // error :(
  } 
  else if(response){
console.log(body);
  }
  else {
     res.sendStatus(200); //successful :)
  }
}) });
app.listen(process.env.port || 3000,function(res){
  console.log('Running on the port 3000');
});
```

I have filled the all required details in my HTML code . But its still throwing an error.

```js
{
    "type": "https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/errors/",
    "title": "Resource Not Found",
    "status": 404,
    "detail": "The requested resource could not be found.",
    "instance": "88703c8b-6d2a-2306-9198-2f2d9317cae4"
}
```